# How do you configure servers?

Tags: sitecore-client, configuration, setup

I am currently configuring a CD Server and a CM server but looking at the spreadsheet (downloaded from the official site: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server) and checking the Sitecore's file extension one by one is really exhausting.

Is there any way to make this easy?
I first thought of PowerShell but the spreadsheet's format is just not helpful enough to code them.

Answer (score 1):

I had used a console app which allowed me to change the file name. Below is the code snippet of the console app

```
public static void UpdateConfigs()
{
    var filesWithPath = DirSearch(@"C:\path\to\app config folder\Include");

    string[] configNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Enable Configs.txt");

    var counter = 0;

    foreach (var configName in configNames)
    {
        if (filesWithPath.ContainsKey(configName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Changing {configName}");
            File.Move(filesWithPath[configName], Path.ChangeExtension(filesWithPath[configName], ".disabled"));

            counter++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Total: {counter}");

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static Dictionary<string, string> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    var files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
    {
        files.Add(Path.GetFileName(f), f);
    }

    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        DirSearch(d);
    }

    return files;
}
```

The Enable Config is only 1 column. You just need to copy all the names from the header **Config file name**. Below is an example of the text file entries

[image]

You just need to update the `.disabled`. Follow the below steps

1. If you are disabling configs, filter the excel sheet and set it to disabled.
2. Copy the names from the **Config file name** and paste it into the text file.
3. Execute the code.

***Note***

You need to change the `.disabled` to blank if you need to enable the config file.